# Javascript/JQuery search

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
```

How I can search if a value exists in the above in javascript/jquery?

The `$.inArray` doesn't work and always returns -1

Comment: What happened when you tried `$.inArray`?

Comment: @Robert Columbia It always returns -1

Comment: That probably means it's not there

Comment: @Andrew L. but it is

Comment: @MATH000 Show how you used it?

Comment: _if (arr.[indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)(char) > -1) {_

Comment: @MATH000 instead of using jQuery, why not use the built in javascript methods, try reading the documentation for array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array there's even a section called "Find the index of an item in the Array"

Answer (score 0):

Use the includes function:

```
arr.includes('c')
true
arr.includes('x')
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Customize a function

```
function contains(arr, obj) {  
    var i = arr.length;  
    while (i--) {  
        if (arr[i] === obj) {  
            return true;  
        }  
    }  
    return false;  
}
```

Use example：

```
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);  
contains(arr, 2);//return true  
contains(arr, 4);//return false
```

Comment: The thing is, there are builtin methods, no need for a time-consuming linear search

Answer (score 0):

try inArray and that should work for you:

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

if($.inArray(a, arr) != -1){
    alert('value is Array!');
} else {
    alert('Not an array');
}
```

Comment: Make sure to enclose a in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,
Suppose you want to check if "a" exists on the given array 'arr',

```
if( $.inArray("a",arr) != -1)
{
   alert("'a' exixts in Array 'arr' ");
}
else
{
   alert("'a' does'nt exixts in Array 'arr' ");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

var char = 'c';
arr.indexOf(char) // return 2

var char = 'x';
arr.indexOf(char) // return -1

if(arr.indexOf(char) != -1) {
    // found
}

arr.findIndex(function(char){ return char === 'c' }) // return 2
```